# HttpClient, Unirest and a 403 in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, httpclient, okhttp, unirest

I am trying to understand the following problem when issuing a GET-request to an API in Kotlin.

When sending the request with Unirest ...

```
val response: com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse<String>? =
  Unirest.get(url)
    .header(
      headerKey,
      headerValue
    )
    .asString()

response?.let {
  println("${response.code}")
}
```

... I get a response code of 200. All fine.

But when I send it with HttpClient ...

```
val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(URI.create(url))
  .GET()
  .header(
    headerKey,
    headerValue
  )
  .build()
val response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
println(response.statusCode())
```

... the response code is 403! Same when I am using Retrofit and OkHttp.

The `headerKey` is "Authorization" and `headerValue` is "Bearer ...somekey...".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and it was simple: The user agent was missing in the header.

Therefore I had to add this line to the request-instantiation:

```
.header("User-Agent", "HttpClient")
```

Here is the full example:

```
val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build()
val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(URI.create(url))
  .GET()
  .header(authHeaderKey, authHeaderValue)
  .header("User-Agent", "HttpClient")
  .build()
val response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
println(response.statusCode())
```